# CSS Sibling selector malfunctioning under Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-selectors

I'm making a vote system and here's my code. It works fine under Firefox, but it's not working properly under Chrome and I don't know what's the problem with it. 
Under Firefox when you hover over each square the previous are selected.
Under Chrome to select the first one you need to point over the second square and so on. 
One more thing, if you click over the fifth box despite its not colored the link is working.

http://jsfiddle.net/SV8Dh/

```
<div id="vote-stars">

    <input type="radio" name="stars" id="5" class="but" value="5"  />
    <label for="5">5</label>

    <input type="radio" name="stars" id="4" class="but" value="4"  />
    <label for="4">4</label>

    <input type="radio" name="stars" id="3" class="but" value="3"  />
    <label for="3">3</label>

    <input type="radio" name="stars" id="2" class="but" value="2"  />
    <label for="2">2</label>

    <input type="radio" name="stars" id="1" class="but" value="1"  />
    <label for="1">1</label>              

</div>
```

Some css:

```
input[type="radio"]{
    display:none;
}

.but + label
{
    width: 23px;
    height: 23px;
    background-color:gray;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    float: left;
    border:1px;
    border-style: groove;
    border-color: yellow;
}

.but:hover + label,
.but:hover ~ .but + label,
.but:hover ~ label {
    width: 23px;
    height: 23px;
    background-color:green;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    margin: 0px;

}
.but:checked + label,
.but:checked ~ .but + label,
.but:checked ~ label {
    width: 23px;
    height: 23px;
    background-color:green;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border:2px;
    border-style: groove;
    border-color: green;
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Does Chrome still have this problem? Amazing.

Comment: Yes, check it's behavior under FF and then under Chrome to see the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems it is caused by changing the display type of the radio buttons to `none` and Chrome has no idea to trigger `:hover` for the hidden element.

As an alternative, you can use `:hover` pseudo-class for the `label`s instead.

```css
label:hover,
label:hover ~ label {
    width: 23px;
    height: 23px;
    background-color: green;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/SV8Dh/1/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simple change Radio Button to visibility:hidden;